# How to fix a multiple assignment issue? on Rails 4

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have 3 tables Accounts, Users, and Subscriptions all of which have the deleted_at column. Now when I delete an account the request gets sent to all models at once causing a Multiple Assignments error as shown below:

```
Started DELETE "/admin/accounts/3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-27 19:38:48 +0200
Processing by SaasAdmin::AccountsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"qo8NxYhezJUz2YylGxHlx2ou125UNoRuEcXbrnzyiN4=", "id"=>"3"}
  AppSetting Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "app_settings".* FROM "app_settings" ORDER BY "app_settings"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Tag Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE "tags"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 22]]
  SaasAdmin Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "saas_admins".* FROM "saas_admins" WHERE "saas_admins"."id" = 4 ORDER BY "saas_admins"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Account Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE (accounts.deleted_at IS NULL) AND "accounts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "3"]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Subscription Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "subscriptions".* FROM "subscriptions" WHERE (subscriptions.deleted_at IS NULL) AND "subscriptions"."subscriber_id" = $1 AND "subscriptions"."subscriber_type" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["subscriber_id", 3], ["subscriber_type", "Account"]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "subscriptions" SET deleted_at = '2014-10-27 17:38:48.909001', deleted_at = '2014-10-27 17:38:48.909025' WHERE (subscriptions.deleted_at IS NULL) AND "subscriptions"."id" = 3
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  multiple assignments to same column "deleted_at"
: UPDATE "subscriptions" SET deleted_at = '2014-10-27 17:38:48.909001', deleted_at = '2014-10-27 17:38:48.909025' WHERE (subscriptions.deleted_at IS NULL) AND "subscriptions"."id" = 3
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms

 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  multiple assignments to same column "deleted_at"
: UPDATE "subscriptions" SET deleted_at = '2014-10-27 17:38:48.909001', deleted_at = '2014-10-27 17:38:48.909025' WHERE (subscriptions.deleted_at IS NULL) AND "subscriptions"."id" = 3):
  activerecord (4.0.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:791:in `async_exec'
```

Additionally, the sql is generated by act as paranoid gem, so we don't write the finder. We do account.destroy, the rest goes by dependecies. Here's the link to the gem if helpful: https://github.com/ActsAsParanoid/acts_as_paranoid

What can we do to fix this?

See the full logs below by visiting the Gist link: https://gist.github.com/rmagnum2002/2358536587bb34dbbc52

Comment: Can you post the code you wrote to trigger the soft delete?

Comment: diego.greyrobot: sure -  account = current_account
    @account.destroy

Comment: How are you setting `@account`? Try posting the full code in a code block in your answer.